# Change Azure virtual machine name in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azureportal

Can we change the name of an Azure Virtual Machine in the Azure portal? I am sure we cannot change it via portal, do we have any PowerShell cmdlet to change the virtual machine name??

Note: I am not referring to VM name inside the VM, but the name that is displayed in the Azure Portal.

Comment: Sorry, the resource name is immutable. Capture image and re-create the virtual machine with the new name.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Resource names for virtual machines are immutable. So, you will need to redeploy your virtual machine.

Best way to do this is to delete the current one, maintaining the disks, and then create a new one with the correct name pointing to those disks.

Answer (score 3):

[Ryanman already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60233453) a script originally written by Oliver Miossec. However, this script only works for Windows VMs.

<s>I added an argument (-osType) to specify the osType so it also works for Linux VMs.</s>

Update 1:
I updated the script to auto detect the Os of the Source VM

Update 2:
Added new Parameter "-newSubnetId" which will move the VM to a new vnet or subnet (needs to be on the same subscription)

You need to specify the full URL of your subnetID like:

```
/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<ressourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<virtualNetworkName>/subnets/<subnetName>
```

```
#Deletes and recreates a VM
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$vmOldName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$vmNewName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$rgName,
    [string]$newLocation, #Optional, moves the VM to a new Geographic Location
    [string]$newSubnetId #Optional, moves the VM to a new Subnet
)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

Write-Host "Get and shutdown old VM, Create new config"
$SourceVmObject = get-azvm -Name $vmOldName -ResourceGroupName $rgName

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($newLocation)) {    
    $newLocation = $SourceVmObject.Location
    Write-Host "No new location specified, using the current VM's existing location: $newLocation"
}

$SourceVmPowerStatus = (get-azvm -Name $SourceVmObject.Name -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName -Status).Statuses | where-object code -like "PowerState*"

if ($SourceVmPowerStatus -ne "VM deallocated") {
    stop-azVm -Name $SourceVmObject.Name -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName -Force
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30 #Wait to ensure VM is shutdown.
}

$NewVmObject = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $vmNewName -VMSize $SourceVmObject.HardwareProfile.VmSize 

Write-Host "Create new Network Objects"
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($newSubnetId)) {    
    $subnetID = (Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceId $SourceVmObject.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].id).IpConfigurations.Subnet.id
    Write-Host "No new Subnet specified, using the current VM's existing subnet: $subnetID"
} else {
    $subnetID = $newSubnetId
    Write-Host "new Subnet specified, $subnetID"
}


$nic = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name "$($vmNewName.ToLower())-0-nic" -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName  -Location $SourceVmObject.Location -SubnetId $SubnetId 

Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $NewVmObject -Id $nic.Id

Write-Host "Move OS Disk"
$SourceOsDiskSku = (get-azdisk -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName -DiskName $SourceVmObject.StorageProfile.OsDisk.name).Sku.Name

$SourceOsDiskSnapConfig =  New-AzSnapshotConfig  -SourceUri $SourceVmObject.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.Id -Location $SourceVmObject.Location -CreateOption copy

$SourceOsDiskSnap = New-AzSnapshot -Snapshot $SourceOsDiskSnapConfig  -SnapshotName "$($SourceVmObject.Name)-os-snap"  -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName

$TargetOsDiskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -AccountType $SourceOsDiskSku -Location $SourceVmObject.Location -CreateOption Copy -SourceResourceId $SourceOsDiskSnap.Id

$TargetOsDisk = New-AzDisk -Disk $TargetOsDiskConfig -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName -DiskName "$($vmNewName.ToLower())-os-vhd"

Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $NewVmObject -ManagedDiskId $TargetOsDisk.Id -CreateOption Attach $SourceVmObject.StorageProfile.OSDisk.OsType

$NewVmObject.StorageProfile.OSDisk.OsType = $SourceVmObject.StorageProfile.OSDisk.OsType
$NewVmObject.StorageProfile.OSDisk.Name = "$($vmNewName.ToLower())-os-vhd"

Write-Host "Create new Data Disks"
Foreach ($SourceDataDisk in $SourceVmObject.StorageProfile.DataDisks) { 

    $SourceDataDiskSku = (get-azdisk -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName -DiskName $SourceDataDisk.name).Sku.Name

    $SourceDataDiskSnapConfig =  New-AzSnapshotConfig  -SourceUri $SourceDataDisk.ManagedDisk.Id -Location $SourceVmObject.Location -CreateOption copy

    $SourceDataDiskSnap = New-AzSnapshot -Snapshot $SourceDataDiskSnapConfig  -SnapshotName "$($SourceVmObject.Name)-$($SourceDataDisk.name)-snap"  -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName

    $TargetDataDiskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -AccountType $SourceDataDiskSku -Location $SourceVmObject.Location -CreateOption Copy -SourceResourceId $SourceDataDiskSnap.Id

    $TargetDataDisk = New-AzDisk -Disk $TargetDataDiskConfig -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName -DiskName "$($vmNewName.ToLower())-$($SourceDataDisk.lun)-vhd"


    Add-AzVMDataDisk -VM $NewVmObject -Name "$($vmNewName.ToLower())-$($SourceDataDisk.lun)-vhd" -ManagedDiskId $TargetDataDisk.Id -Lun $SourceDataDisk.lun -CreateOption "Attach"
}

Write-Host "Creating..."
New-AzVM -VM $NewVmObject -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName -Location $SourceVmObject.Location
Write-Host "VM Created..."
```

Answer (score 2):

Credit to Oliver Miossec for this non-destructive azure powershell script that creates a new VM, with some changes for parameters. You can find his post [here](https://dev.to/omiossec/using-powershell-to-rename-move-or-reconnect-an-azure-vm-i00). It's extra awesome because it'll also fix badly-named discs and NICs associated with the machine.

```
#Deletes and recreates a VM
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$vmOldName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$vmNewName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$rgName,
    [string]$newLocation #Optional, moves the VM to a new Geographic Location
)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

Write-Host "Get and Shutdown old VM, Create new config"
$SourceVmObject = get-azvm -Name $vmOldName -ResourceGroupName $rgName

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($newLocation)) {    
    $newLocation = $SourceVmObject.Location
    Write-Host "No new location specified, using the current VM's existing location: $newLocation"
}

$SourceVmPowerStatus = (get-azvm -Name $SourceVmObject.Name -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName -Status).Statuses | where-object code -like "PowerState*"

if ($SourceVmPowerStatus -ne "VM deallocated") {
    stop-azVm -Name $SourceVmObject.Name -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName -Force
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30 #Wait to ensure VM is shutdown.
}

$NewVmObject = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $vmNewName -VMSize $SourceVmObject.HardwareProfile.VmSize 

Write-Host "Create new Network Objects"
$subnetID = (Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceId $SourceVmObject.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].id).IpConfigurations.Subnet.id

$nic = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name "$($vmNewName.ToLower())-0-nic" -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName  -Location $SourceVmObject.Location -SubnetId $SubnetId 

Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $NewVmObject -Id $nic.Id

Write-Host "Move OS Disk"
$SourceOsDiskSku = (get-azdisk -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName -DiskName $SourceVmObject.StorageProfile.OsDisk.name).Sku.Name

$SourceOsDiskSnapConfig =  New-AzSnapshotConfig  -SourceUri $SourceVmObject.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.Id -Location $SourceVmObject.Location -CreateOption copy

$SourceOsDiskSnap = New-AzSnapshot -Snapshot $SourceOsDiskSnapConfig  -SnapshotName "$($SourceVmObject.Name)-os-snap"  -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName

$TargetOsDiskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -AccountType $SourceOsDiskSku -Location $SourceVmObject.Location -CreateOption Copy -SourceResourceId $SourceOsDiskSnap.Id

$TargetOsDisk = New-AzDisk -Disk $TargetOsDiskConfig -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName -DiskName "$($vmNewName.ToLower())-os-vhd"

Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $NewVmObject -ManagedDiskId $TargetOsDisk.Id -CreateOption Attach -Windows

Write-Host "Create new Data Disks"
Foreach ($SourceDataDisk in $SourceVmObject.StorageProfile.DataDisks) { 

    $SourceDataDiskSku = (get-azdisk -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName -DiskName $SourceDataDisk.name).Sku.Name

    $SourceDataDiskSnapConfig =  New-AzSnapshotConfig  -SourceUri $SourceDataDisk.ManagedDisk.Id -Location $SourceVmObject.Location -CreateOption copy

    $SourceDataDiskSnap = New-AzSnapshot -Snapshot $SourceDataDiskSnapConfig  -SnapshotName "$($SourceVmObject.Name)-$($SourceDataDisk.name)-snap"  -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName

    $TargetDataDiskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -AccountType $SourceDataDiskSku -Location $SourceVmObject.Location -CreateOption Copy -SourceResourceId $SourceDataDiskSnap.Id

    $TargetDataDisk = New-AzDisk -Disk $TargetDataDiskConfig -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName -DiskName "$($vmNewName.ToLower())-$($SourceDataDisk.lun)-vhd"


    Add-AzVMDataDisk -VM $NewVmObject -Name "$($vmNewName.ToLower())-$($SourceDataDisk.lun)-vhd" -ManagedDiskId $TargetDataDisk.Id -Lun $SourceDataDisk.lun -CreateOption "Attach"
}

Write-Host "Creating..."
New-AzVM -VM $NewVmObject -ResourceGroupName $SourceVmObject.ResourceGroupName -Location $SourceVmObject.Location
Write-Host "VM Created..."
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing any issue in connectivity to your VM's from internal VM's/Application instances. you can change the name in /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname. 
After editing these two files, you need to restart the instance.

vi /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain

vi /etc/hostname

localhost.localdomain

Answer (score 0):

In Azure VM resources names cannot be modified once deployed so the best practice is to keep the disks and creating a New VM with a the appropriate name following the previous disks.

Answer (score -2):

You can not rename VM Name but you can Update VM Size, even move VM to one subscription to other/change resource group.